# Python: Wallpaper added using ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW() gets removed after restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I wrote the program at the end of the question to download an art work image from https://thisartworkdoesnotexist.com and then save it in a jpg file and then set that jpg as wallpaper. After this, I wrapped it up into a tkinter gui. This program works as I have expected when clicking the button but the wallpaper does not remain after restart. It shows a black screen as wallpaper instead.
I am posting the whole code because I can't understand what the problem is and can't guess where the problem is.

```
import shutil
import ctypes
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import requests
import os
print('imported')
working_dir = 'C:\\art-wall'


def magic():
    download()
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0,'C:\\art-wall\\file.jpg' , 0)
print('magic')

def download():
    url = 'https://thisartworkdoesnotexist.com/'
    shutil.rmtree(working_dir)
    os.mkdir(working_dir)
    content = requests.get(url).content
    open('C:\\art-wall\\file.jpg', 'wb').write(content)

print('download')

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

style = Style()

style.configure('TButton', font=
('calibri', 20, 'bold'),
                borderwidth='4')

style.map('TButton')

btn1 = Button(root, text='Quit !', command=root.destroy)
btn1.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=100)

btn2 = Button(root, text='Change Wallpaper', command=magic)
btn2.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To troubleshoot: 1. Does `C:\art-wall\file.jpg` still exist after a reboot? 2. If you set it as the wallpaper manually instead of with Python, then does it persist across reboots?

Comment: The file.jpg exists after reboot. And after setting wallpaper manually, the wallpaper exists after reboot

Comment: Set the last parameter of `SystemParametersInfoW` to 3.  See the duplicate.